# AngularJS service does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I want to create dynamic page title in my webapp. I've created service which should helps me, but it does not work. PageTitleService.getTitle() always returns undefined. Is there someting wrong? What should be corected to run this code? Here is the code:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/index', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main/index.html',
    controller: 'PageController'
}); 
$routeProvider.when('/pages/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'views/page/show.html',
    controller: 'PageController'
});                         
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/index'
});
});
app.defaultPageName = 'home';
app.name = 'Custom name';
```

PageTitleService.js:

```
app.factory('PageTitleService',
function() {
    var title;
    return {
        setTitle : function(t) {
            title = t;
        },
        getTitle : function() {
            return title + ' - ' + app.name;
        }
    }
});
```

AppController.js

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'PageTitleService',
function($scope, PageTitleService) {
    $scope.pageTitle = PageTitleService.getTitle();
}]);
```

PageContorller.js

```
app.controller('PageController',
['$location', '$routeParams', '$scope', 'PageService', 'PageTitleService',
    function($location, $routeParams, $scope, PageService, PageTitleService) {
        var pageName = $routeParams.name !== undefined ? $routeParams.name : app.defaultPageName;
        var page = PageService.getPage(pageName);

        PageTitleService.setTitle(page.title); //page.title is always a string

        $scope.title = page.title;
        $scope.content = page.content;
    }
]);
```

index.html (begin):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="AppController">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line the `AppController` is run once.

```
$scope.pageTitle = PageTitleService.getTitle();
// we didn't set title before, getTitle() returns undefined.
```

After that, you can change title with `setTitle('something')` but `$scope.pageTitle` will still be undefined.

Instead, what you can do is:

```
$scope.getPageTitle = PageTitleService.getTitle;
```

Then in the view

```
<span ng-bind="getPageTitle()"></span>
```

To use it.

Comment: One more question. What is the difference between 
<span>{{ getPageTitle() }}</span> and <span ng-bind="getPageTitle()"></span>

Comment: They essentially do the same thing, however, before the angular application is compiled, the user will see {{ getPageTitle() }} in raw form (not compiled), in ng-bind, it will be empty. e.g. You can even do <span ng-bind="postCount">?</span>. So it will show "?" before it is ready then how the number.

Answer (score 0):

From my first impression I would suggest to try this:

```
app.factory('PageTitleService',
function() {
    this.title = "home";
    var self = this;
    return {

        setTitle : function(t) {
            self.title = t;
        },
        getTitle : function() {
            self.title + ' - ' + app.name;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If it would be write in that way, you won't have to write getter and setter.